# Toggle selected elemens class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically loaded table with the following tr's:

```
        <tr>
            <td><span class="active">Task Name</span><br /><span class="icons_small">U</span><span class="contact_name tiny">Contact Name</span><span class="user_number tiny">(111111)</span><span class="icons_small" style="visibility:hidden;">!</span></td>
            <td><span class="date_assigned">13/12/2012</span><br /> <div id="progressbar"></div></td>
            <td class="icons_small"><span class="flag_task">f</span></td>
            <td class="icons_small"><span class="set_reminder">A</span></td>
            <td><span class="warning tiny" style="visibility:hidden;">Delete</span></td>
        </tr>
```

Im trying to set the td with the spanclass "flag_task" (3rd td down) to toggleclass an additonal class, but only on the selected td with the spanclass "flag_task, not all instances of that class. This is what im currently using:

```
            <script>
               $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () { 
                    $(".flag_task").click(function () {
                        $(".flag_task").toggleClass("warning");
                    });    
               });
            </script>
```

Could someone please clarify how to effect only the selected instance.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: By "selected" do you mean clicked?

Comment: Dynamically loaded table as in contents loaded dynamically or table created dynamically? Does the click even trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this section of the code, you're saying "grab all elements with a class of `flag_task`" instead of just "grab the clicked element."

```
$(".flag_task").click(function () {
    $(".flag_task").toggleClass("warning");
});
```

So, to fix this issue, you just have to select the element that was clicked on.

This line:

```
$(".flag_task").toggleClass("warning");
```

Can be changed to:

```
$(this).toggleClass("warning");
```

Check out [Understanding the "this" keyword](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/)

Comment: I swear I tried that, but must have overlooked something. Works now, thanks! I'll award you the answer asap.

Comment: @EricHotinger, you got the right answer +1. I also learned here that a "explained answer" is preferred to a "fast answer" :)